# combining get-wmiobject, get-acl and get-childitem

Tags: powershell, acl, get-childitem, fileserver, get-wmiobject

I am trying to capture the shares on a given file server. Then getting the ACL (access control list) from a share (doing this manually atm). Then from that share, getting the get-childitem. Can someone help me consolidate this to one line?

Eventually I will have to dump the output to a CSV.

**Get all shares**

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Computer SERVER01 | FT path, name -AutoSize
```

**Get ACL from a given share**

```
(Get-ACL C:\FileShare\testFolder01).Access
```

**Get-ChildItem from a given share**

```
Get-ChildItem C:\FileShare\testFolder02 -Rec | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Extension | sort DirectoryName, Name
```

Comment: "to a csv" - how do you imagine each row will look?

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner for something like that would be pretty crazy do-able but crazy. When ever I run into this I use a loop of some kind normally a foreach and then create a PS custom object. Below is a great blog post on how to create custom PS objects. I'd recommend looking at doing that.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/02/04/creating-powershell-custom-objects/